# scp did not finish successfully (1)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on module which will transfer file from one server to another using ruby on rails. I am using `Net::SCP` for the same but getting the following error. When googled i found it should folder permissions or path issue but it isn't. I have proper permissions (write permission) on folder and both source and destination path exists.

```
scp = Net::SCP.start(host,username, :ssh => {:password => "****"})
scp.upload!(src_file,destination_path)
```

> Error :  SCP did not finish successfully (1)

**Note:** host username and password are all correct

Comment: Try to execute from shell `scp src_file username@host:destination_path`.

Comment: Would you please provide a full backtrace of the error you get.

Comment: Make sure you have ssh, scp requires it.

Comment: yeah ssh is available on my machine. using ubuntu 14.0